# Can someone please explain how to create this complex SOAP Request via PHP?

Tags: php, api, soap, wsdl, soapui

Here is the SOAP Request I need to send, which works perfectly in the SOAP UI program and returns a valid response.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="http://www.escapia.com/EVRN/2007/02">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ns:EVRN_UnitDescriptiveInfoRQ Target="Production" Version="1.0">
            <ns:POS>
                <ns:Source>
                <ns:RequestorID ID="username" MessagePassword="password"/>
                </ns:Source>
            </ns:POS>
            <ns:UnitDescriptiveInfos>
                <ns:UnitDescriptiveInfo/>
            </ns:UnitDescriptiveInfos>
        </ns:EVRN_UnitDescriptiveInfoRQ>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Here is what I've tried in PHP...

```
$wsdl = 'https://api.escapia.com/EVRNContentService.svc?wsdl';

$options = array(
    'trace' => false
);

$client = new \SoapClient($wsdl, $options);

$xmlr = new SimpleXMLElement('<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="http://www.escapia.com/EVRN/2007/02">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ns:EVRN_UnitDescriptiveInfoRQ Target="Production" Version="1.0">
            <ns:POS>
                <ns:Source>
                <ns:RequestorID ID="username" MessagePassword="password"/>
                </ns:Source>
            </ns:POS>
            <ns:UnitDescriptiveInfos>
                <ns:UnitDescriptiveInfo/>
            </ns:UnitDescriptiveInfos>
        </ns:EVRN_UnitDescriptiveInfoRQ>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>');

$params = new SoapVar($xmlr, XSD_STRING);

try {
    $response = $client->UnitDescriptiveInfoStream($params);

    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($response);
    echo '</pre>';
} catch (SoapFault $e) {
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($client);
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

However this just returns a response of..

```
object(stdClass)#4 (1) {
  ["any"]=>
  string(388) "Failed to authenticate anonymous client. Source array is missing from request."
}
```

Please if anyone has any idea how to correctly make this request via PHP, that would be greeeeat.

Comment: Have you tried doing it via cURL?

Comment: If you are not using `soapui`, it can be removed from tag.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly advise you to use a WSDL to php generator so you won't wonder how to construct the request. In addition, the response will be easy to handle.

Try the [PackageGenerator](https://github.com/WsdlToPhp/PackageGenerator) project

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used `PackageGenerator` but I've had success with something like this:

```
$xmlr = new SimpleXMLElement(...);

$params = new stdClass();
$params->xml = $xmlr->asXML();

$response = $client->UnitDescriptiveInfoStream($params);
```